# Present continuous tense for a babitual or repeated thing - verb choices

Tags: tense, present-continuous

Present continuous tense can be used to describe Longer Actions in Progress.

The example are from Englishpage.com

> I am studying to become a doctor.

> I am not studying to become a dentist.

> I am reading the book Tom Sawyer.

> I am not reading any books right now.

> Are you working on any special projects at work?

> Aren't you teaching at the university now?

It seems to me that only more abstract verbs such as teach, study, work on can be used this way, but I am not sure.

Can I use other types of verbs also?

**Example 1**

> I am **manufaturing** a new car model.

**Example 2**

> We am **building** a new office.

**Example 3**

> He is **eating** salad every friday to stay in shape.

**Example 4**

> She is **practicing** English recently because she plans to go abroad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

> [The company] is manufacturing a new model. (Cars of this type are currently in production)
>
> We are building a new office. (Work is in progress **or** will begin soon.)
>
> He is eating salad every Friday. (Describes a habit.)

You can't use the present continuous with *recently.* Either *She is practising English* (currently) **or** *She has been practising English recently.*